# ¿Cómo recorrer este array en php?

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando con php CodeIgniter y estoy obteniendo resultados de una consulta los cuales los guardo en el siguiente array

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    $arr[] = array("id"=>$row->id, "nom"=>$row->nombre);
}
```

Pero no he encontrado como recorrer el array con el fin de usar los valores "id" y "nom" de cada indice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si almacenas tus datos en un array de esta forma:

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    $arr[] = array("id"=>$row->id, "nom"=>$row->nombre);
}
```

Puedes accederlos uno por uno de esta otra:

```
foreach ($arr as $row)
{
    $id     = $row['id'];
    $nombre = $row['nom'];
}
```

Lo que te estás creando en un array multidimensional donde cada valor es un array asociativo que almacena los valores `$row->id` y `$row->nombre` obtenidos mediante la consulta para cada registro, asignándolos a las claves 'id' y 'nom'. Así para acceder a un dato concreto, por ejemplo la ID del tercer registro obtenido, tendrás que acceder usando primero la posición, para acceder al array asociativo y luego el indice asociado al dato ID dentro de este:

```
$arr_row = $arr[2];
$id = $arr_row['id'];
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta

Comment: De nada, a ti por acordarte de votar. ¡Feliz año!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar para obtener el resultado de la query, siendo $resultado lo que obtuviste de la consulta:

```
$resultado->result_array();
```

Luego es mas sencillo obtener los campos porque utilizas:

```
<?php foreach($resultado as $rows =>$row){

 echo $row['id'];
 echo $row['nombre'];
}
```

De esta forma extraes fácilmente los valores arrojados en la consulta `SQL`. `"id"` y `"nombre"` es justo como se llaman los campos en tu tabla por lo que si en tu tabla tienes un campo que se llame "apellido" para obtener cada uno de los indices del resultado de la consulta de `"apellido"` deberías hacer:

```
<?php
foreach($resultado as $rows =>$row){

 echo $row['apellido'];
}
```

Esa es la solución Un saludo!